# What are some good ways to output arrays of data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I had this code to output columns of data:

```
interestRow =table(Position,Hertz,Auxiliary_Channel_Power,Main_Channel_Power);
writetable(interestRow,auxiliaryData,'Delimiter','\t','WriteRowNames',true);
```

However, the cluster I'm working on does not have a new version of Matlab, so I can't use table.
How can I use fprintf to print out columns?
What I have right now is:

```
fprintf('%f \t %f \t %f\t%f\t',Position,Hertz,Auxiliary_Channel_Power,Main_Channel_Power);
```

But it's not working.
And are there any other better methods that work on older versions of Matlab?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Does it give an error? Does it run but doesn't do what you expect? If there is an error message, what is it? What type of variables do you have?

Comment: It's not what I expect. It puts it all on one line

Comment: `\n` will force a newline, just as `\t` makes a tab. Can you see how your question was difficult to answer without that extra information?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can create a matrix from all the data:

```
total_matrix = [Position,Hertz,Auxiliary_Channel_Power,Main_Channel_Power];
```

Then you can write it to a file:

```
dlmwrite(filename,total_matrix, 'delimiter','\t','precision',3 );
```